# Function type mismatch when implementing abstract method

Tags: scala, function, abstract, traits

I'm new to Scala, I'm stuck on this problem unfortunately.

I have a function type defined in `Types.Subscribe` that I want to reuse as follows:

```
object Types {
  type Subscribe[T] = (T => T)
}

trait Adapter[T] {
  def subscribe: Types.Subscribe[T]
}

class IntAdapter extends Adapter[Int] {
  def map(subscribe: Types.Subscribe[Int]) = { 1 }
  def subscribe(value: Int): Int = { 2 }
}
```

However, I get the following error from IntelliJ:

> Class FooAdapter must either be declared abstract or implement
>   abstract member 'subscribe: Types.Subscribe[T]'

It seems that `def subscribe(value: Int): Int` does not match function type `(Int => Int)`, which is a bit confusing. If that's the case, how can I define a Subscribe function type that I would be able to reuse as described above?

I tried defining the function type using the apply method:

```
trait StreamSubscribe[T] {
  def apply(value: T): T
}
```

However, I could not get this to work either.

I want to have a single source of truth for the type signature of the subscribe method, instead of repeating it in random places. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Your trait `Adapter` has `def subscribe` and your `IntAdapter` has `def subscribe(value: Int)`. Notice any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be mixing two concepts class functions (aka methods) and anonymous functions. Although at the core both are just functions you can't define a class function the way you would like but you *could* use it as you would expect.

Not sure exactly how you would utilize the function but I believe this is what you are looking for...

```
object Types {
  type Subscribe[T] = (T => T)
}

trait Adapter[T] {
  /**
    *
    * @return a function which takes a [[T]] and returns a [[T]]
    */
  // def subscribe: Types.Subscribe[T]

  /**
    * @param value a [[T]]
    * @return a [[T]]
    */
  def subscribe(value: T): T
}

class IntAdapter extends Adapter[Int] {
  def map(subscribe: Types.Subscribe[Int]) = {
    subscribe(1)
  }

  def subscribe(value: Int): Int = {
    value + 2
  }
}

val adapter = new IntAdapter()
adapter.map(adapter.subscribe) // returns 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Adapter.subscribe` is a "parameterless method type" with result `Subscribe[T]`, or `=> Subscribe[T]` or `=> T => T`.

Nothing unusual about that, but your `IntAdapter.subscribe` takes parameters, `Int => Int`, and doesn't override.

You can do this:

```
scala> object X { type F[A] = A => A }
defined object X

scala> trait T[A] { def f: X.F[A] }
defined trait T

scala> class TI extends T[Int] { def fImpl(i: Int) = 2 * i ; def f = fImpl }
defined class TI

scala> new TI().f(42)
res0: Int = 84
```

where `fImpl` becomes `(i: Int) => fImpl(i)`.

Or using notational conveniences:

```
scala> class TI extends T[Int] { def f = 2 * _ }
defined class TI
```